# Comparing n with (n-1) and (n-2) records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SQL statement which can generate the list of customers whose minutes Streamed is consistently less than the previous minutes Streamed. As in minutes Streamed in the nth order is less than minutes Streamed in n-1th order, and the next previous order is also less. Another way to say it, list the customers that watch less and less minutes each time they watch a movie.

The table, query:

[sqlfiddle link:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39c909/111)

I have come up with the following query:

```
select distinct c1.customer_Id
from Customer c1
join Customer c2 
where c1.customer_Id = c2.customer_Id
  and c1.purchaseDate > c2.purchaseDate
  and c1.minutesStreamed < c2.minutesStreamed;
```

This query doesn't deal with the (n-1)st and (n-2)nd comparison, i.e. "minutes Streamed in the nth order is less than minutes Streamed in n-1th order, and the next previous order is also less." condition.

I have attached a link for sqlfiddle, where I have created the table.

Comment: Use `ON` instead of `WHERE` to be ANSI SQL compliant. (And portable.)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Continuous Learner,

the following statement works for the `n-1` and `n-2` relation.

```
select distinct c1.customer_Id 
from Customer c1 
join Customer c2 
on c1.customer_Id = c2.customer_Id
join Customer c3
on c1.customer_Id = c3.customer_Id
where c1.purchaseDate < c2.purchaseDate
and c1.minutesStreamed > c2.minutesStreamed
and c2.purchaseDate < c3.purchaseDate
and c2.minutesStreamed > c3.minutesStreamed
```

Although, I currently don't have an automatic solution for this problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I  would use a ROW_NUMBER() function with partition by customer id.
and then do a self join, on customer id and rank = rank-1, to bring new and old at the same level

Like:
`create temp_rank_table as 
 (
  select 
    customer_Id,
    purchaseDate ,
    minutesStreamed,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_Id, ORDER BY purchaseDate, minutesStreamed) as cust_row
 from Customer 
)`

self join

`select customer_Id
( select
     newval.customer_Id,
     sum(case when newval.minutesStreamed < oldval.minutesStreamed then 1 else 0 end) as LessThanPrevCount,
     max(newval.cust_row) as totalStreamCount
    from temp_rank_table  newval
    left join temp_rank_table  oldval
    on newval.customer_id = oldval.customer_id
    and newval.cust_row-1 = oldval.cust_row -- cust_row 2 matches to cust_row 1 
    group by newval.customer_id
)A
where  A.LessThanPrevCount = (A.totalStreamCount-1)
-- get customers who always stream lesser than previous
--you can use having clause instead of a subquery too`

Comment: Does MySQL support ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: I don't think so. Might have to find a work around for it.

Comment: Found a workaround right here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) Answer given by Mosty Mostacho should work here

Answer (score -1):

> DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE ( [NO] INT, [CODE] VARCHAR(50), [AREA]
>   VARCHAR(50) )
>
> /* EXAMPLE 1 */ INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES
>   (1,'001','A00') INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES
>   (2,'001','A00') INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES
>   (3,'001','B00') INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES
>   (4,'001','C00') INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES
>   (5,'001','C00') INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES
>   (6,'001','A00') INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES
>   (7,'001','A00')
>
> /* EXAMPLE 2 */ /* ***** USE THIS CODE TO ENTER DATA FROM DIRECT TABLE
>   ***** SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FIELD_DATE]) AS [NO] ,[FIELD_CODE] AS [CODE] ,[FIELD_AREA] AS [AREA] FROM TABLE_A WHERE
>   CAST([FIELD_DATE] AS DATE) >= CAST('20200307' AS DATE) ORDER BY
>   [FIELD_DATE],[FIELD_CODE]
>   */
>
> SELECT A.NO AS ANO ,A.CODE AS ACODE ,A.AREA AS AAREA ,B.NO AS BNO
>   ,B.CODE AS BCODE ,B.AREA AS BAREA ,CASE WHEN A.AREA=B.AREA THEN
>   'EQUAL' ELSE 'NOT EQUAL' END AS [COMPARE AREA] FROM @TBL A LEFT JOIN
>   @TBL B ON A.NO=B.NO+1
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: Hi! Please, consider formatting your answer and adding some explanation to it. Thank you!